# Laravel socialite keeps redirecting me on home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am trying to setup a Linkedin & Google sign-in for my Laravel 5 / Angular 2 website using Laravel socialite package.

Socialite provider and alias are correctly inserted in `config/app.php` file

Here is the code I inserted in `config/services.php` file

```
'linkedin' => [
    'client_id' => '[hidden-linkedin-client-id]',
    'client_secret' => '[hidden-linkedin-client-secret]',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8888/profile',
],

'google' => [
    'client_id' => '[hidden-google-client-id]',
    'client_secret' => '[hidden-google-client-secret]',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8888/profile',
],
```

Here are the routes I created...

```
Route::get('/auth/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

...and the related functions in `Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php`

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    Log::info('redirecting');
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    return $user->token;
}
```

Then when I navigate to http://localhost:8888/auth/github or http://localhost:8888/auth/linkedin it keeps redirecting me to http://localhost:8888 without any log. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: did you try to put something `dd("here..")` in `redirectToProvider` function?

Comment: @K.Toress thanks for help. Just tried with `Log::info('redirecting')` and indeed, I do not see any log. What can be wrong here?

Comment: Umm then the redirection happens before hits the controller function, can post your routes.php file if its not much big?

Comment: @K.Toress it is actually pretty big (around 100 routes). The other routes work great. The routes I am using for Socialite are listed in my question. I tried inserting them at the top and at the bottom of the file -> same result

Comment: do you have other routes with `/auth` or are you using `middlewares`, `route groups` for these two routes?

Answer (score 0):

Update Configurations for social redirect, Check Below:-

```
'linkedin' => [
    'client_id' => '[hidden-linkedin-client-id]',
    'client_secret' => '[hidden-linkedin-client-secret]',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8888/auth/linkdin/callback',
],

'google' => [
    'client_id' => '[hidden-google-client-id]',
    'client_secret' => '[hidden-google-client-secret]',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8888/auth/google/callback',
],
```

and Redirect function should be like this:-

```
public function redirectToProvider(){
  try{
    Log::info('redirecting');
    return Socialite::driver(\Request::segment(2))->redirect();
  }catch(\Exception $e){
    Log::info('Exception in redirect');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help but none of your answers actually worked since the `redirectToProvider()` function is not called.

So I kept my initial code and finally made it working by commenting these lines in the middleware `Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        /* 
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/');
            }
        */
        return $next($request);
    }
```

This is clearly a workaround but this is the best solution I found yet.